# NetBeans C - HelloWorld - ошибка компилятора

Tags: c, netbeans, компиляция, компилятор

Что сделать, что бы он писал нормальным шрифтом в отладке вместо квадратиков?
И что за ошибка, почему не запускает код?

[image: Почему не хочет запускать код?]

Answer (score 1):

**Во-первых, можно сменить шрифт на тот, который поддерживает русский:**

Правый клик в окно терминала -> Настройки (Параметры, Установки или что там у Вас, не знаю. У меня Settings) -> Далее выберите шрифт (например, monospaced)

**Во-вторых, можно сменить локализацию на английскую в файле XML с настройками:**

Идете в директорию с установленной IDE, в папке *etc* должен быть файл *netbeans.conf* . В конец строки *netbeans_default_options* добавляете *--locale en_US* , и получаете NetBeans на английском, в которой таких проблем как у Вас точно не возникнет.

**В-третьих, какой набор компиляторов вы используете?**

Если mingw, то вам необходимо установить msys для сборки ваших проектов:

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/MSYS-1.0.11.exe

Установите в папку со сборником компиляторов.

(есть еще способы установить MSYS: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS)

Далее, добавьте путь к MSYS к переменной Path OC: [image: Скрин]

И вот вам скрин с путями к исполняемым файлам компилятора: [image: Скрин 2]

Надеюсь, что помог! Удачи!

Возникнут вопросы - прошу оставить комментарий, помогу! :)